# I want advice on receiving and sending web socket messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, websocket, twilio

I have followed a tutorial to write an application that I can call via Twilio SDK, which opens a WebSocket connection. I am using spring boot and now I want to be able to talk in the phone and transcribe it to text with Azure cognitive services do some stuff with the text. Convert the text back to speech and send it to the phone. My problem is that when I say something I get it to Azure and get it back but in the phone it is repeated many times. Instead of once. Here is how the method for receiving and sending messages through the socket looks:

```
@Override
public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    JsonNode request = jsonMapper.readTree(message.getPayload());

    if (request.path("media").path("track").asText().equals("inbound")) {
        String base64EncodedAudio = request.path("media").path("payload").asText();

        if (payloads.size() > 200) {
            String response = contructResponse(session, request);
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(response));
            payloads.clear();
        } else {
            payloads.add(base64EncodedAudio);
        }
    }
}

private String contructResponse(WebSocketSession session, JsonNode request) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String streamSid = request.path("streamSid").asText();

    for (int i = 0; i < payloads.size(); i++) {
        byte[] decoded = base64Decoder.decode(payloads.get(i));
        sessions.get(session).pushData(decoded);
        decoded = sessions.get(session).getBytes();

        if (decoded != null)
            outputStream.write(decoded);
    }

    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(outputStream.toByteArray());

    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new OutBoundMessage("media", new Media(new String(encodedBytes)), streamSid));
}
```

My hope was that once I had received 200 messages I would concatenate the audio from these, do the azure handling, and send back one message since List payloads is cleared after that and not greater than 200. But it does not seem so. Is it working on a different thread while all the azure stuff is going on on another thread and keep adding messages before clearing payloads? Any one have some input?

Comment: Without Azure the message back is only repeated once, so it seems it has something to do with Azure

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is going on here, but my guess is that calls to `constructResponse` and `session.sendMessage` are perhaps taking longer than it takes for another websocket message to arrive, so the process is repeating before you are able to clear `payloads`.

Can you clone `payloads`, clear the original `payloads` list and then pass the clone to the `constructResponse` method?

Something like:

```java
@Override
public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    JsonNode request = jsonMapper.readTree(message.getPayload());

    if (request.path("media").path("track").asText().equals("inbound")) {
        String base64EncodedAudio = request.path("media").path("payload").asText();
        payloads.add(base64EncodedAudio);

        if (payloads.size() > 200) {
            // Clone the current members of payloads, I think this will work, excuse the type if it's wrong
            ArrayList<String> clonedPayloads = payloads.clone();
            payloads.clear();

            String response = contructResponse(clonedPayloads, session, request);
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(response));
        }
    }
}
```

Then change `constructResponse` to receive the cloned payloads list as an argument:

```java
private String contructResponse(ArrayList<String> payloads, WebSocketSession session, JsonNode request) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String streamSid = request.path("streamSid").asText();

    for (int i = 0; i < payloads.size(); i++) {
        byte[] decoded = base64Decoder.decode(payloads.get(i));
        sessions.get(session).pushData(decoded);
        decoded = sessions.get(session).getBytes();

        if (decoded != null)
            outputStream.write(decoded);
    }

    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(outputStream.toByteArray());

    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new OutBoundMessage("media", new Media(new String(encodedBytes)), streamSid));
}
```

Comment: It is not the best question, a bit messy. But I tried your solution and the problem is still there. I will need to dig deeper.

Comment: If you can update your code in the question to the latest you have, I might be able to suggest more?